# How do I use css last-child?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a list of comments and I want to set the `border-radius` of the last child using some css code comment divs like this
[image: comment form]
i'm using this code but it doesn't work.

```
 #comments>.comment:last-child, .indented>.comment:last-child{border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;}
```

it works when using with jquery like this

```
 $('#comments>.comment:last, .indented>.comment:last').css('border-bottom-right-radius', '10px');
```

but i want to solve it using css code.Any suggestions?

fiddle for simple code [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/farnabaz/93tZV/)

Comment: i check it on both safari and firefox

Comment: And what problem are you trying to solve? What's the end-result that you want?

Comment: i want to create like picture, but by my css code only last div have border radius and 2 uppers haven't border radius, like sample in fiddle

Comment: Your HTML structure is flawed. You should be using UL/LI elements.

Comment: Which element should have the border-radius? the `.comment`, the `.meta`, another element entirely?

Comment: @DavidThomas `.comment` elements

Comment: @ŠimeVidas the structure created by **drupal** and not mind, i just write a theme for it, and i can't change HTML structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been able to make it work (for the provided HTML structure) with this CSS code:

```
#comments > .comment:nth-last-child(-n+2),
.indented > .comment:nth-last-child(-n+2) {
    border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
}
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/93tZV/3/

So, instead of using `:last-child` to select the last child, we use `:nth-last-child(-n+2)` to select the last two children. This works if the last child is an `.indented` DIV, since our `.comment` selector will filter it out. However, if both last children are `.comment` DIVs, the CSS styles will apply to both of them, which results in http://jsfiddle.net/93tZV/4/ I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: thank you very much, its work fine, i fix this problem to, here final solution http://jsfiddle.net/farnabaz/KAJsp/

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML structure has flaws so the alternative solution is add `right_bottom_round` class where you want the right bottom rounded.

```
.right_bottom_round {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px !important;
}
```

and check the [browser compatibility here](http://caniuse.com/css-sel3)

Comment: the `!important` should be unnecessary.

Comment: don't work, may i write wrong css to select elements? simple fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/farnabaz/93tZV/1/

Comment: @Farnabaz i tried alot but there is problem in you html as [@ Sime vids](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12448281/how-do-i-use-css-last-child/12448307#12448307) says so i have updated the alternative way to do this